# Sbt run command for multiple projects

Tags: scala, sbt

I have multiple projects in one directory, which are aggregated in sbt. I would like to write a task for sbt in build.sbt, which would make some commands in each project.

```
lazy val P1 = (project in file("P1")
lazy val P2 = (project in file("P2")
lazy val cleanEverywhere = taskKey[Unit]("Clean everywhere")
```

How am I supposed to write this cleanEverywhere task to clean each project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
val cleanAll = taskKey[Unit]("Clean all projects")
cleanAll := clean.all(ScopeFilter(inAnyProject)).value
```

where [`all`](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/1e25bc917c259c8b3c31ace06aba3fe4ee73da4d/main/src/main/scala/sbt/ScopeFilter.scala#L75)

> Evaluates the task in all scopes selected by the filter

and [`inAnyProject`](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/1e25bc917c259c8b3c31ace06aba3fe4ee73da4d/main/src/main/scala/sbt/ScopeFilter.scala#L106) selects all [scopes](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Scopes.html#Scope+axes) along project axis.

Answer (score 3):

Another way is to restructure your `build.sbt` as following

```scala
    lazy val root = (project in file(".")).aggregate(p1, p2)

    lazy val p1 = project.in(file("p1"))
    lazy val p2 = project.in(file("p2"))
```

this way, whenever you run `sbt clean`, `sbt test`, `sbt compile` commands, every command will get executed against all the aggregated projects and you don't need to create `cleanAll` task

And if you want project specific command, you can run it like `sbt p1/compile`